# jQuery Popup not scrollable with Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, scroll

I can scroll through the popups that I created with jQuery in every browser except Firefox. In Firefox the scrollbar works, but not the mouse scroll: http://benjamintuercke.com/portfolio.html

How do I make it work with Firefox? I already changed "overflow: auto" and "overflow: hidden" to "overflow: scroll" in CSS, but that didn't help. I've googled a lot, but I didn't find the solution to my problem.

Can you please help me?

HTML:

```
      <div class="Details1">
        <div class="Hintergrund"></div>
        <div class="MeineWebsiteE"></div>
        <div class="X2"></div>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
  .Details1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .Details1:hover {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
```

jQuery:

```
    $("#Detailclick1").on("click", function () {
      $(".Details1").css("z-index", "2");
      $(".Details1").fadeIn(500);
      $(".portfolio").css("position", "fixed");
      $("header").fadeOut(500);
    });
```

".portfolio" is what you see when you don't have a popup opened. I set the position to "fixed" whenever a popup is opened so that you only scroll through the popup and not through ".portfolio" in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `Hintergrund` element is not allowing you to scroll as its position is fixed. It will be better if we remove this element and give background in popup container itself i.e. `.Details1`

HTML:

```
  <div class="Details1">
    <div class="MeineWebsiteE"></div>
    <div class="X2"></div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .Details1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.85); // for getting transparent background
  }

  .Details1:hover {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I owe you a favor, so if you need anything let me now.